# How do I increase or decrease the size of a button in Swift?

Tags: ios, animation, swift, coordinates

I have a `UIButton` in my app that I call "buttonPlay". I am using AutoLayout but the button doesn't have any `NSLayoutConstraints` attached to it.

I would like to code an animation **to increase and the decrease the height and the width** of the button. Here's how the animation code looks like:

```
    // "Repeat" because the animation must repeat itself
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: {
        // Animation code goes here
        // nil: the animation is not supposed to end
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

To get the **original values of the x position, y position, width and height** I am using the following code:

```
var frmPlay : CGRect = self.buttonPlay.frame

// get the current x and y positions
        let originXbutton = frmPlay.origin.x
        let originYbutton = frmPlay.origin.y

// get the current width and height of the button     
        let originWidthbutton = frmPlay.size.width
        let originHeightbutton = frmPlay.size.height

// set the frame (frmPlay) to the button frame
        self.buttonPlay.frame = frmPlay
```

Okay, it's now time to increase or decrease the width and the height of the animation. I'll put this code inside the `animation` block:

```
        self.buttonPlay.frame = CGRectMake(
            originXbutton,
            originYbutton,
            originWidthbutton-100,
            originHeightbutton)

        self.buttonPlay.frame = CGRectMake(
            originXbutton,
            originYbutton,
            originWidthbutton+100,
            originHeightbutton)
```

The animation code will look something like this:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: {

        println("Animation function animateStuff() started!")

        var frmPlay : CGRect = self.buttonPlay.frame

        let originXbutton = frmPlay.origin.x
        let originYbutton = frmPlay.origin.y

        let originWidthbutton = frmPlay.size.width
        let originHeightbutton = frmPlay.size.height

        self.buttonPlay.frame = frmPlay

        self.buttonPlay.frame = CGRectMake(
            originXbutton,
            originYbutton,
            originWidthbutton-100,
            originHeightbutton)

        self.buttonPlay.frame = CGRectMake(
            originXbutton,
            originYbutton,
            originWidthbutton+100,
            originHeightbutton)

        }, completion: nil)
```

Let's run the app. Uh oh! The button (also called buttonPlay) **doesn't get bigger or smaller in any way**. Though it moves from right to left. But hey! I haven't touched the x and the y positions code.

What causes it?

Comment: what do you mean by increase and decrease? Do you mean first increase then after that decrease one after the other?

Comment: Yes! Increase and after that decrease to that the width and the height matches the original width and height. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat` and `UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse` together to do that. You just have to set one frame change inside the animation block. You cannot have more than one state change to the same property inside an animation block.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.6, options:
    UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

    println("Animation function animateStuff() started!")

    var frmPlay : CGRect = self.buttonPlay.frame

    let originXbutton = frmPlay.origin.x
    let originYbutton = frmPlay.origin.y

    let originWidthbutton = frmPlay.size.width
    let originHeightbutton = frmPlay.size.height

    self.buttonPlay.frame = frmPlay

    self.buttonPlay.frame = CGRectMake(
        originXbutton,
        originYbutton,
        originWidthbutton+100,
        originHeightbutton)

    }, completion: { finished in

})
```

> UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat : Repeat the animation indefinitely.
>
> UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse : Run the animation backwards and
>   forwards. Must be combined with the UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
>   option.

If you want to scale the button up and down,

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.6, options:
    UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

        self.buttonPlay.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
    }, completion: { finished in

})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This code just moves the button to the left and to the right, again and again. It doesn't increase or decrease the width/height of the `UIbutton` Have you got any fix? Thanks again!

Comment: did you use the exact same code I gave? It doesn't move left to right. it increases the width and then decreases the width. Do u mean you want to scale it up and down?

Comment: Yes! Your code makes sense! In fact, you are adding up some width with       `originWidthbutton+100` but it just doesn't work.

Comment: I have added the code for scaling  at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I just wanted to THANK YOU SO MUCH. This scaling up code works! I expressed myself the wrong way. I should have used the "scaling" term.

Comment: So the scaling is doing pretty good! I love how you used efficiently `UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse` to get the jobs done. But the button is not clickable now. When I lay my finger on the button there is no shadow-hover-effect. What can cause it? Thanks!

Comment: added `UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction` to the code to enable click

Answer (score 1):

Put separate animations for increasing and decreasing button size .Try this code .

This will decrease the button size with animation .

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: {

    println("Animation function animateStuff() started!")

    var frmPlay : CGRect = self.buttonPlay.frame

    let originXbutton = frmPlay.origin.x
    let originYbutton = frmPlay.origin.y

    let originWidthbutton = frmPlay.size.width
    let originHeightbutton = frmPlay.size.height

    self.buttonPlay.frame = frmPlay

    self.buttonPlay.frame = CGRectMake(
        originXbutton,
        originYbutton,
        originWidthbutton-100,
        originHeightbutton)
    }, completion: nil)
```

This will increase the size again to original button .

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: {

    println("Animation function animateStuff() started!")

    var frmPlay : CGRect = self.buttonPlay.frame

    let originXbutton = frmPlay.origin.x
    let originYbutton = frmPlay.origin.y

    let originWidthbutton = frmPlay.size.width
    let originHeightbutton = frmPlay.size.height

    self.buttonPlay.frame = frmPlay

    self.buttonPlay.frame = CGRectMake(
        originXbutton,
        originYbutton,
        originWidthbutton+100,
        originHeightbutton)

    }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution in `Swift 3`:

```
func animate(sender: UIButton) {

    let buttonSize: CGRect = sender.frame

    let originXbutton = buttonSize.origin.x
    let originYbutton = buttonSize.origin.y

    let originWidthbutton = buttonSize.size.width
    let originHeightbutton = buttonSize.size.height

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        sender.frame = CGRect(x: originXbutton, y: originYbutton - 5, width: originWidthbutton + 3, height: originHeightbutton + 3)
    }, completion: { finished in
        sender.frame = CGRect(x: originXbutton, y: originYbutton, width: originWidthbutton, height: originHeightbutton)
    })
}
```

[image]